# Query result is not correct

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having something wrong with my query results. It is not displaying the correct rows with the "QuestionContent" field.

For example in the database table if it states (not included all fields):

```
QuestionContent     Option Type    QuestionMarks     Answer   ....// other fields

What is 2+2         A-D            1                  D
What is 3+3         A-D            1                  B
What is 4+4         A-E            2                  C
```

Then why when I create my query that the result display's this:

```
QuestionContent     Option Type    QuestionMarks     Answer   ....// other fields

What is 2+2         A-D            1                  D
What is 3+3         A-D            1                  D
What is 4+4         A-D            1                  D
```

Below is the query I am using, how can this be fixed to be able to display the correct result?

```
SELECT q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, a.Answer, r.ReplyType,
       q.QuestionMarks
FROM Answer a                
INNER JOIN Question q ON a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
      JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
      JOIN Question qu ON r.ReplyId = qu.ReplyId
      JOIN Option_Table o ON qu.OptionId = o.OptionId
GROUP BY q.QuestionContent
```

UPDATE: BELOW is the schema of the 4 tables:

Question Table:

```
SessionId (PK)  Varchar(3)
QuestionId(PK)  INT
QuestionContent Varchar(250)
NoofAnswers     INT
QuestionMarks   INT
ReplyId(FK)     Varchar(2)
OptionId(FK)    Varchar(2)
```

Answer Table

```
  SessionId (PK)  Varchar(3)
    QuestionId(PK)  INT
    Answer          Varchar(10)
```

Option_Table Table

```
  OptionId(PK)    Varchar(2)
  OptionType        Varchar(10)
```

Reply Table

```
  ReplyId(PK)    Varchar(2)
  ReplyType        Varchar(10)
```

In the Query I want to display these fields:

```
QuestionContent 
OptionType
NoofAnswers
Answer
ReplyType 
QuestionMarks
```

Hope that is enough information, if not please comment to me :)

Comment: if you copy and paste here part of your script you will help more accuracy help, http://sqlfiddle.com/ It's hard redesign queries without all the information.

Comment: It would help if you provided the outline schema of the 4 tables, and their various primary and foreign key relationships.

Comment: Updated question to include schema of tables

Comment: Thanks for the update.  So, the combination of SessionID plus QuestionID is unique; there could be multiple sessions using the same QuestionID?  Are there in fact multiple sessions in the data?

Comment: Please note that there was no way for us to infer from the original question (without the schema) that the SessionID column existed, much less that you were not joining on the full primary of the question and answer tables.  This is why the schema is so important. (And this is a comment addressed to everyone who asks SQL questions - not just at you.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes you are right, I should of included the schema much eariler. The SessionId is the Exam number and the QuestionId is the Question number, so for example Question 1 in Exam AAA is stores as SessionId AAA, QuestionId 1, If I want to look at question 1 in a different exam paper (AAD), then it is SessionId AAD, QuestionId 1. I am just going to re-do the Answer Table because I don't think I have done that table correctly and then I will test your answer :) I upvoted your answer because of the complete effort you have put in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the primary key of the Question table is SessionID + QuestionID, and that the primary key of the Answer table is also SessionID + QuestionID, you must specify the join on those two tables on both columns:

```
FROM Answer   AS a
JOIN Question AS q ON q.SessionID = a.SessionID AND q.QuestionID = a.QuestionID
```

Without both, you end up with a Cartesian product effect when a question ID appears in more than one session.

Also, since you are not selecting SessionID, you will need to deal with duplicate results where two different sessions have the same question and answer information. I think SELECT DISTINCT is probably better than GROUP BY for the purpose.  Reserve GROUP BY for when you have aggregates (such as COUNT(*) or SUM(expression)) and do not use it for general 'duplicate elimination'.

---

#### Original commentary

I believe there are are two parts to your problem — one possibly not crucial, the other probably crucial.

Your query is, more or less:

```
SELECT q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, a.Answer, r.ReplyType,
       q.QuestionMarks
FROM Answer a                
INNER JOIN Question q ON a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
      JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
      JOIN Question qu ON r.ReplyId = qu.ReplyId
      JOIN Option_Table o ON qu.OptionId = o.OptionId
GROUP BY q.QuestionContent
```

For some reason, you've listed Question in that twice, but there's no evidence that you need the second alias for it.  On that basis alone, you can simplify the query to:

```
SELECT q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, a.Answer, r.ReplyType,
       q.QuestionMarks
  FROM Answer       AS a                
  JOIN Question     AS q ON a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
  JOIN Reply        AS r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
  JOIN Option_Table AS o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
 GROUP BY q.QuestionContent
```

That is the possibly not crucial change; you appeared to have a 1:1 join.  The optimizer might be able to ignore the superfluous second reference to the Question table, but not mentioning that which is not used is better.

The probably crucial issue is the GROUP BY clause.  In most dialects of SQL, you'd need to list all of the non-aggregate selected values in the GROUP BY clause.  In this query, where there are no non-aggregates shown, that would mean listing all 6 result columns.  When you don't do this, MySQL takes things somewhat at random.  My suspicion is that you need to reveal whether there are any aggregates in the full query, and explain what the GROUP BY is supposed to do for you.  I'm not sure whether simply omitting it will give you the answer you need, or whether you need to do something else.  One reason for the lack of certainty is the lack of schema in the question; we cannot tell all that much about the schema of the tables and the primary key, foreign key relationships between them.

So, I'd recommend using (trying):

```
SELECT q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, a.Answer, r.ReplyType,
       q.QuestionMarks
  FROM Answer       AS a                
  JOIN Question     AS q ON a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
  JOIN Reply        AS r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
  JOIN Option_Table AS o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
```

If that gives 'the wrong number of rows', then you need to explain the schema and the relationships between the rows.

Comment: I have included schema in the question

Comment: BTW there could be a chance that mutiple rows in the question table could have the same QuestionContent, so is it wise to Groupby SessionId and QuestionId so we know which QuestionContent belongs to which Question Number in a particular session?

Comment: Roughly - yes.  See amendment to answer (about SELECT DISTINCT).  Or include the SessionID in the selected data (I'd probably do that).  I'd be leery of using GROUP BY in the absence of any aggregate; doubly so with MySQL which doesn't require all non-aggregate columns to be listed in the GROUP BY clause, but which leaves the results for the other columns ... under-specified or non-deterministic?

Answer (score 1):

Question:Answer is always going to be a 1:1 ratio, for multiple choice. There's no reason you shouldn't be able to put the answer column in the question table. You can use 'option type' as a foreign key and link it to your various sets of potential question types, as you just mentioned.

Edit: I've re-designed for multiple answers per question now.

So a design like:

```
QuestionContent     QuestionID(PK)    QuestionMarks     AnswerID(PK)   ....// other fields

What is 2+2         1                    1                  1
What is 3+3         1                    1                  2
What is 4+4         2                    2                  3
```

and 'Option Table'

```
QuestionID(FK)     Option Type

1         A-D           
2         A-E            
3         A-C
```

Now an answer table

```
AnswerID(Fk) Answer

1         A           
1         B
2         A            
3         C
3         A
```

This now leaves you with an arbitrary amount of Answer types, and allows multiple Answers per question.

Comment: I have included schema in my question. So looking at the schema do you think there is no pioin of me having an Answer Table?

Comment: I meant to say is there no point of me having an Answer Table?

Comment: As long as it's one answer to one question, then no, you don't need an answer table. If there's multiple answers to one question, however, yes you need the answer table.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how you would create a Answer Table where it stores in single and Multiple Answers? Because some questions could he multiple answers but I think the way I have done it is completley incorrect. Is it suppose to be 1 AnswerId holds 1 answer and then somehow call on multiple id's if a question has multiple answers?

Comment: Updated with the  support of multiple answers per question.

Comment: Hi, I am a little bit confused. In your Example where is says AnswerId '1', does that mean that for Question 1 the answer is A and B? Or does it mean like AnswerId 1 shows that this answer combination is A and B, AnswerId 2 is combination A and C, and AnswerID 3 is just A? If it is doesn't that mean I will have loads of diffeent combinations because Answer could be between A-Z (either single or multiple answers) so there could be loads ofdifferent combinations.

Comment: So in your Example if Question 1 (QuestionId = 1) answer is A and B, then does the AnswerId in the Question Table need to equal 1 to link up with AnswerId 1 in Answer Table.

Comment: It depends on how you'd like to query it. You can use the OR conditional, and the answer is A OR B, or you could use the AND conditional and the answer is then A AND B.

Comment: What I mean is that if I add a question into database, and Answer is A B, then how does AnswerId in Quesion Table store this so it is able to retrieve Answer A B from Answer Table?

Comment: Each question has a unique answerID assigned to it. You then link it to the Answer Table based on that unique ID. Any answer associated with that question, will have that ID associated with it. So a new question would have QuestionID of 4. Then you'd add two more rows to Answer Table: AnswerID 4 Answer A; and 
AnswerID 4 Answer B.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting answer from the the different table. (a.amswers) You should do q.Answer.

Comment: But I don't have answer field in Question Table, I only have answer field in "Answer" Table. Show I include an AnswerId in the Question table and link the Id to the Answer Table by createing an AnswerId field in the Answer Table?

Comment: If I do the comment above then I will have a massive answer table as for can be loads of different types of answers. Answer could be A, C, V and then next answer could be A,D,E,L,Z and etc, that is why I have just done it like this

Comment: But then you are not linking answer id in Question and answer table. I guess you need to give the structure of all tables involved.

Comment: I have included schema in the question